# Can we move code from ts file to tsx file in the react SPFx, will it work?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-custom-property-pane

In react SPFx, property pane fields and interface was there in the .`ts` file while creating react SPFx project. I want to use it in `.tsx` file.

Will it work or not?

Because in every web part, `.ts` file gets created automatically. I want to reduce number of files that's why I want to merge it.